# Cumulative resource usage

Tags: users, monitoring, htop

I'm managing a few compute servers w/ roughly 20 users each. I'm using `htop` to view current resource usage, however it would be very helpful to have a log of a specific user's cumulative memory and cpu usage. Is there any way to view/log this via `htop` or bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `top -bn1 -U {user}` to create a file which you can then do additional processing on to gain a cumulative usage.

The argument `-bn1` makes `top` run in a non-interactive mode, simply outputting once when finished. You can then pipe that output anywhere for additional processing.

for example,

`top -bn1 -U {user} > user_log.txt` for additional processing in another script,

or you could do something like,

`top -bn1 -U {user} | awk {file_processing_script} >> user_log.txt`

`file_processing_script` in that case is an `awk` script that processes the data in whatever way you want. one idea could be `awk 'NR>7{cpu += $9; mem += $10} END {printf "%.2f\t%.2f\n", cpu, mem}'`, which will simply output the total cpu and memory usage from a specific user at the moment it is run. Append several of these together, and you get a nice table showing cpu and memory usage from a user.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want: `htop -u someusername`

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I've been using. The issue is that requires me to already know the "problematic" user. I'm looking for a way to find these users by viewing cumulative resource usage.